# error: invalid operands to binary expression (map use find function error)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
class __ME
{
public:
    int age;
    __ME()
    {
    }
    __ME(int a)
    {
        age = a;
    }
    void Run()
    {
        if (age)
        {
            cout << "age" << age << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "run..." << endl;
        }
    }
};

template <class K, class V>
class value_equals
{
private:
    K key;

public:
    value_equals(const K &vt) : key(vt)
    {
    }
    bool operator==(pair<const K, V> &elem)
    {
        return elem->first == key;
    }
};

int main()
{
    map<string, __ME *> *me1 = new map<string, __ME *>();
    me1->insert(map<string, __ME *>::value_type("lyl", new __ME()));
    me1->insert(map<string, __ME *>::value_type("lx1", new __ME()));
    map<string, __ME *>::iterator it = find(me1->begin(), me1->end(), value_equals<string, __ME *>("lyl"));
    cout << it->first << endl;
}
```

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, __ME *>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char>, __ME *>, void *> *,
      long> >::value_type' (aka 'pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, __ME *>') and 'const value_equals<std::__1::basic_string<char>, __ME *>')
        if (*__first == __value_)
            ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
```

I don't know what I did wrong in this code.
I hope you can give me a suggestion.

Comment: Start with `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: It would help to explain what you are trying to do.  If you are looking for a string you can get rid of `value_equals` (which is strangely named considering it matches on keys, not values) and change the `find` line to `auto it = me1->find("lyl");`

Comment: `__ME` is a reserved identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code work you need to modify your operator definition slightly:

```
template <class K, class V>
class value_equals
{
private:
    K key;

public:
    value_equals(const K &vt) : key(vt)
    {
    }
    bool operator==(const pair<const K, V> &elem) const
    {
        return elem.first == key;
    }
};

template <class K, class V>
bool operator==(const pair<const K, V> &lhs, const value_equals<K,V>& rhs)
{
    return rhs == lhs;    
}
```

`std::find` was trying to do `element == value` and your implementation was only providing `value == element`. You also need to make sure you put `const` in all the correct places.

If you use `std::find_if` this becomes a little simpler:

```
template <class K, class V>
class value_equals
{
private:
    K key;

public:
    value_equals(const K &vt) : key(vt)
    {
    }
    bool operator()(const pair<const K, V> &elem) const
    {
        return elem.first == key;
    }
};

map<string, __ME *>::iterator it = find_if(me1->begin(), me1->end(), value_equals<string, __ME *>("lyl"));
```

However the simplest (and most efficient) of all is to use the built in find support of `std::map`:

```
map<string, __ME *>::iterator it = me1->find("lyl");
```

Note that `cout << it->first << endl` without checking `it != me1->end()` would lead to undefined behaviour if the element is not found.

Note that `__ME` is a reserved identifier and shouldn't be used in your code. Any identifier starting with `__` or identifier starting with a single `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for use by the compiler/standard library.

Comment: You are really great! Thank you